# How would one filter a form collection in Symfony2?

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm rewriting an old application to Symfony2 and I'm a bit stuck. The application has `TaskType` and `TagsType`. The `TaskType` form has a collection of `TagType`. Some of the tags might be archived (i.e. `Tag#archived=true`). If that's the case, the archived tags should not be shown in the form when you try to edit the task.

```
class TaskType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title')
            ->add(
                'tags',
                'collection',
                array(
                    'type'         => new TagType(),
                    'allow_add'    => true,
                    'allow_delete' => true,
                    'by_reference' => false,
               )
            )
        ;
    }

    // ...
}


class TagType extends AbstractType
{
    /**
     * @param FormBuilderInterface $builder
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
        ;
    }

    // ...
}
```

Is there a way to filter the tags similar to using `query_builder` when having an `entity` instead of `collection`? Is there any workaround at all?

Comment: Why don't you use query_builder direclty into TagType, passing Task id (optional parameter?). I'm not sure if I understood the question correclty btw.

Comment: Could you show `TagType` too?

Comment: @DonCallisto It's quite simple - with the setup above, in the form you would see all tags. I would like to exclude some of the tags in the collection (i.e. `SELECT * FROM tags WHERE archived = false` instead of `SELECT * FROM tags`). Could you post an example of your idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is the case for the whole system that archived tags arent shown to the user, you might want to use a global filter since it's similar to "deletable" behaviour.

You can look at the code here

https://github.com/Atlantic18/DoctrineExtensions/blob/master/lib/Gedmo/SoftDeleteable/Filter/SoftDeleteableFilter.php

Softdeletable lets you ignore "softly deleted" entities, while you want to ignore "archived" tags. It's quite advanced example since it uses annotations and such, what you would need to check is only if queried class is "Tag" and simply return " AND Tag.archived = 0" or whatever

Comment: I saw this while researching earlier today. I was wondering, though, if there's a built-in symfony way, but I guess not for now.  Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Another thing is to to manually filter the data on PRE_SET_DATA form event. The collection widget is supposed to just dipsplay givent data, it is not form's job to filter data already existing in the entity that the for is used to edit

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to mark archived tags as "soft-deleted", other option is to make a collection criteria. You can apply the criteria in getTags() method in the Task entity.

```
public function getTags()
{
    return $this->tags->matching(Criteria::create()->where(Criteria::expr()->eq('archived',true)));
}
```

Comment: I'd say this is incorrect, you should not keep such logic in the entity, for sure not in the obvious getter for the field

Comment: If you have one-to-many relation and let's say 1000 related tags (arhived and non-archived), getTags() method in that case would return 1000 tags, which obviously not something you would ever want to do. I only do this, when I need to limit the data and when the criteria will never change. Another option is to write another method getArchivedTags()...

Comment: Unfortunately this solution is not going to work for me as it's exactly the case where you have 1000 related tags you mentioned. This could have worked as a workaround if I had just a couple of tags. :)

Comment: Okay, just remember, rendering of the "Form" with more than 50 objects mapped to the fields, turned out very slow for me, it took couple of seconds.

Comment: I could imagine. In my situation, though, I would have only about 10-15 objects which are not "soft-deleted", so everything should be working fine. Thanks for the notice! :)